# NSString componentsSeparatedByString

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have a string coming from server. I am identifying a particular substring and then breaking the main string at that substring.

```
NSString *string = /* getting from server */;
NSString *strAddress = /* Substring of string */;
NSArray *arr = [string componentsSeparatedByString:strAddress];
NSString *strBeforeAddress = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
```

This works perfectly fine when `strAddress` has something before it. But in some cases it completely gives a strange result. For example, when

```
string = @"cxzcvxcv\n14, Beaven Dam Road\nVail, CO81657";
strAddress = @"14, Beaven Dam Road\nVail, CO81657";
```

I get only one object in `arr`, the complete string, which I think is wrong. It should give result as 2 objects: `cxzcvxcv` and `blank object`. However, when

```
string = @"14, Beaven Dam Road\nVail, CO81657";
strAddress = @"14, Beaven Dam Road\nVail, CO81657";
```

the array `arr` in this case has 1 object, the complete string. Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Comment: Can you give sample String and strAddress that you are searching for?

Comment: In the future, PLEASE format `code` with back tick and use **bold** only for emphasis. This will make your question infinitely more readable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If

```
 string = @"cxzcvxcv\n14, Beaven Dam Road\nVail, CO81657";
 strAddress = @"14, Beaven Dam Road\nVail, CO81657";
```

Then `strBeforeAddress` will be - `cxzcvxcv\n`

If

```
  string = @"14, Beaven Dam Road\nVail, CO81657";
  strAddress = @"14, Beaven Dam Road\nVail, CO81657";
```

then `strBeforeAddress` will be `nil`.

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to achieve with the string, exactly what string you want from response.

Comment: am also getting same issue, when trying to get city name from lat long.. for some co-ordinates its in 3rd place of array and for some co-ordinates its in 2nd and in some 5th place...

Comment: nil is not the same as @""; the output in the second case is the latter, not the former.

Answer (score 12):

From the [NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) discussion on the method `componentsSeparatedByString:`

> The substrings in the array appear in the order they did in the
>   receiver. Adjacent occurrences of the separator string produce empty
>   strings in the result. Similarly, if the string begins or ends with
>   the separator, the first or last substring, respectively, is empty.
>   For example, this code fragment:
>
> `NSString *list = @"Norman, Stanley, Fletcher";`
>
> `NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];`
>
> produces an array `{ @"Norman", @"Stanley", @"Fletcher" }`.
>
> If list begins with a comma and space—for example, `", Norman, Stanley,
>   Fletcher"`—the array has these contents: `{ @"", @"Norman", @"Stanley",
>   @"Fletcher" }`
>
> If list has no separators—for example, `"Norman"`—the array contains the
>   string itself, in this case `{ @"Norman" }`.

The output of your two test cases are:

```
NSString *string = @"cxzcvxcv\n14, Beaven Dam Road\nVail, CO81657";
NSString *strAddress = @"14, Beaven Dam Road\nVail, CO81657";
NSLog(@"%@",[string componentsSeparatedByString:strAddress]);
```

outputs

```
(
    "cxzcvxcv\n",
    ""
)
```

as expected. And for the second case

```
NSString *string = @"14, Beaven Dam Road\nVail, CO81657";
NSString *strAddress = @"14, Beaven Dam Road\nVail, CO81657";
NSLog(@"%@",[string componentsSeparatedByString:strAddress]);
```

outputs

```
(
    "",
    ""
)
```

again, as expected. I see no problem here.

Comment: According to the documentation the 2nd output should be @"14, Beaven Dam Road\nVail, CO81657" right? Why is it showing 2 blanks?

Comment: @madhavanrp No. The separator is never part of the output. The output is always and only the strings on either side of the separator.